# How to specify hadoop conf directory as a conf property to spark application

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Is there a spark property which we can set while doing spark submit which specifies the hadoop configuration path, specifically to point custom hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to do it would be to set the Hadoop config directory before the spark-submit instead of configuring those files individually.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/your/hadoop/dir
```

But if it has to be set using sparkConfig, you can do it as follows,

```
sparkConfig.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname","XXX");
sparkConfig.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address","XXX:8032");
sparkConfig.set("spark.yarn.access.namenodes","hdfs://XXXX:8020,hdfs://XXXX:8020");
sparkConfig.set("spark.yarn.stagingDir", "hdfs://XXXX:8020/user/hduser/");
```

Entire discussion relevant to this question can be found here,
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file-to-the/m-p/126813